# Device Is Busy When Trying To UMount

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, ddrescue

I am using the Ubuntu Rescue Remix and Ddrescue.  I am in the process of creating a RAW image onto a 'good' drive (sdc) from a 'bad' drive (sdc).  I used the command

```
sudo ddrescue -r 3 /dev/sdb image log
```

to begin the back-up process.  Well I have the "Finished" command on screen so I am trying to unmount my good drive, before a reboot by using the following

```
sudo umount /dev/sdc
```

but I am getting an error of

```
device is busy.
(In some cases useful info about processes that use the device is found by lsoft(8) or fuser(1))
```

My Linux knowledge is very very low so I am not sure what I need to do in order to umount the drive?

EDIT ---
I was following the tutorial listed here http://www.geekyprojects.com/storage/how-to-recover-data-even-when-hard-drive-is-damaged/ and since I was unable to unmount my drive, I just force rebooted.  Well now when I run

```
sudo lshw -C disk -short
```

the drive no longer shows up?!?!?!  These are the drives I see.  It completely skips sdb

```
/dev/sda
/dev/cdrom
/dev/cdrom
/dev/sdc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see some alternatives:

1. Found what process use this filesystem `fuser -v -m /dev/sdc` or `lsof <mountpoit>` (possible Yuo just have proccess with working directory on sdc) as adviced in error mesage.
2. Try force unmount `sudo umount -f /dev/sdc` In this scenario ***some data on sdc can be unsaved***.
3. Dumb but clean - reboot system :-)

Comment: I rebooted but now my system does not see the drive when I run sudo lshw -C disk -short

Comment: It very strange result. Like hardware problem. You Reboot by command `reboot` or buy hardware reset?